# bibitem with multiple citation

Tags: bibliographies, bibitem

On Overleaf, I am using this type of bio:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem{GI}
Belinskii, A, & Klyshko, D. Two-photon optics: diffraction, holography, and transformation of two-dimensional signals. Sov. Phys. JETP 78, 259 (1994).
\bibitem{Pittman}
Pittman, T. B., Shih, Y. H., Strekalov, D. V. & Sergienko, A. V. Optical imaging by means of two-photon quantum entanglement. Phys. Rev. A 52, R34232 (1995).
\bibitem{Thermal}
Gatti, A., Brambilla, E., Bache, M. & Lugiato, L. A. Ghost Imaging with Thermal Light: Comparing Entanglement and Classical Correlation. Phys. Rev. Lett. 93,
093602 (2004).

\end{thebibliography}
```

When I cite `\cite{GI, Pittman, Thermal}`  I'd like [1-3] but I get [1,2,3]. How can I change it?

Comment: You can get what you want either with `\usepackage{cite}` or with `\usepackage[numbers, sort&compress]{natbib}`. (Do not load both packages at the same time!) Since your manual `thebibliography` does not use the optional argument of `\bibitem` to pass on author and year data, it probably makes little sense to use `natbib`, so in your setting I'd go for `\usepackage{cite}`.

Comment: Note that you need to escape your `&`s to `\&`s to avoid errors. `Belinskii, A,` should probably be `Belinskii, A.,`